# viewbased application with tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Im a newbie in ios ,  my app is a single view application (nib), the first view has 2 buttons , the first one open a uiview with 4 buttons , every button open a tabbar , (thats mean 4 bar button items ) ,

the views up show o.k.

at the second button in the first view , a view shows with 3 buttons every button open a tabbar , (thats mean 3 bar button items ) , the problem that when I pressed one of these 3 buttons the app get crashed and shows the error ([UITabBarController presentModalViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance..)

I did the step at the second bar as what i did in the first !

```
-(IBAction)goabout{
 UIViewController *view1 = [[[about alloc] initWithNibName:@"about" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *view2 = [[[collages alloc] initWithNibName:@"collages" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *view3 = [[[centers alloc] initWithNibName:@"centers" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   self.tabBarControllerr = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
   self.tabBarControllerr.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: view1,   view2,view3, nil];
   [self.tabBarController  setSelectedIndex:0];
   [self.tabBarControllerr presentModalViewController:tabBarControllerr animated:NO completion:nil];

   }
```

any help please? 
thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with [self.tabBarControllerr presentModalViewController:tabBarControllerr animated:NO completion:nil]? It looks like the tab bar controller is trying to present itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two properties with very similar, but different names:

- `self.tabBarController` (with one 'r')
- `self.tabBarControllerr` (with two 'r's).

Then, in `goabout` you call `presentModalViewController:animated` on `self.tabBarContollerr` and pass to it `self.tabBarControllerr`

I would make sure that your variable names are not confusing you and I would also then make sure that you mean to call `presentModalViewController:animated` on the proper object.

I don't believe that a `UITabBarController` can present itself. It needs to present a different `UIViewController` instance.

Comment: thank you first, the two uitabbarControllers are different, so I put different names.

Comment: See my edit: The UITabBarController instance is trying to present itself. Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your app? Its difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Do you really want to use an empty view to present a tab bar controller modally?

Comment: check this pic , hope it make sense

Comment: Still not sure what you're doing, but your issue is most likely the fact that you're calling `presentModalViewController:animated` on `UITabBarControllerr` and passing a pointer to `UITabBarControllerr` (the same object!) to present itself. It appears you've realized this, now.

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: If you want two different `UITabBarController`'s, then you should name them in a more descriptive manner. `tabBarController` and `tabBarControllerr` will be very confusing to anyone who tries to come back and read your code, including yourself after you stop working actively on the code for any significant period of time.

Answer (score 0):

[self presentViewController:tabBarControllerr animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: If you have resolved the issue please mark an answer so everyone will know.